# Glitch while using deleteRowsAtIndexPaths and reloadRowsAtIndexPaths together

Tags: uitableview, swift, reload

I seem to have trouble using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` and `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` together.

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is called to update the row.

In my custom ViewCell I'm using a delegate to delete a row in the TableView, using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` whenever I swipe this cell. The labels are set to move along with the swipe and returns if the conditions are not met.

Everything is working just fine until `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` has been called to delete a row. From here on, the next cell behaves strangely and the labels are in a state as when the cell was about to be deleted.

To solve this problem I can use `reloadData()` instead, but I really want to know what causes this behavior instead of being forced to use `reloadData()` all the time.

Code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Code to add item to datamodel
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
}
```

Code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = orderTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("orderViewCell") as! OrderViewCell
    let item = data[indexPath.row]

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.nameLabel.text = item.name;
    cell.amountLabel.text = item.amount
    cell.priceLabel.text = item.price

    cell.amount = item.amount;
    cell.name = item.name

    return cell
}
```

The method handling the deletion:

```
func deleteItem(name: String) {
    if let index = find(data.map { $0.name }, name) {
        data.removeAtIndex(index)
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)
    }
}
```

Comment: Working with `UITableView` animations is one big glitch.